# Dedicated Server restarts with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having some troubles and I hope someone can help. I have a game server that I am running on a dedicated server. I have a batch file that is currently running the server. The server needs to be restarted 4 hours after the server starts. What I am struggling with is the statements to get the batch file to run my restart batch file in 4 hours? If the batch file says run my restart batch in 4 hours my life will be saved.

here is my current batch file.

```html
@echo off
if "%configdone%"=="1" (
 GOTO :EOF
)
set configdone=0
set skbt_debug=2
set keepalive_database=1
set keepalive_bec=0
set keepalive_asm=0
set keepalive_ts=0
set keepalive_hc=0
set serverport=2302
set bindtoip=0
set serverip=118.217.115.72
set bec_flag_dsc=1
set teamspeak_port=2310
set asm_log_interval=5
set serverStartTimeout=10
set db_backup_interval=60
set use_zip_logs=1
set use_zip_backups=1
set databasebackupfolder="E:\Overpoch Server 1\Backup"
set logfilebackupfolder="C:\apps\epoch_log_backups"
set manual_timeout_length=2
set auto_timeout_length=10
set auto_restart_delay=5
set cleanWerDialogs=1
set hclaunchparams=-connect=1 -ip=199.217.115.72 -port=2312 -client -nosound -mod=@Epoch;@EpochHive;@MAS;
set armaserverexe=arma3server.exe
set hcexename=arma3serverHC.exe
set teamspeakfilename=ts3server_win64.exe
set redisexename=redis-server.exe
set becexename=bec.exe
set asmexename=ArmaServerMonitor.exe
set databasefile_name=dump.rdb
set asm_log_file=asm_performance.log
set armapath="C:\servers\epochServer"
set hcarmapath="C:\servers\epochServer"
set teamspeakpath="C:\apps\teamspeak"
set redispath="C:\servers\epochServer\DB"
set asmpath="C:\servers\epochServer"
set Battleyepath="C:\servers\epochServer\SC\BattlEye"
set LogPath="C:\servers\epochServer\SC"
set becpath="C:\servers\epochServer\BEC"
set databasefile="C:\servers\epochServer\DB\dump.rdb"
set servercfgpath="C:\servers\epochServer\SC\config.cfg"
set serverbasicpath="C:\servers\epochServer\SC\basic.cfg"
set profilepathname="SC"
set cli_username="SC"
if %bindtoip%==1 (
 set ip_param= -ip=%serverip%
) else (
 set ip_param=
)
set mod_string=-mod=@Epoch;@EpochHive;@MAS;
set servercommandline=%armaserverexe% "%mod_string:"=%" "-config=%servercfgpath:"=%" %ip_param% -port=%serverport% "-profiles=%profilepathname:"=%" "-cfg=%serverbasicpath:"=%" "-name=%cli_username:"=%" -autoinit
set serverAffinity=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
set becAffinity=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
set hcAffinity=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
set redisAffinity=2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1
set teamspeakAffinity=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
set asmAffinity=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
set serverPriority=normal
set becPriority=normal
set hcPriority=normal
set redisPriority=normal
set teamspeakPriority=normal
set asmPriority=normal
```

This is my restart batch

```html
@echo off
call "C:\servers\EPOCHS~2\batch\ULTSGS~1.CMD"
cd /D %armapath%
if %skbt_debug% GTR 2 (
 call :FUNC NOVAR BatchLogWrite 3__AUTO_RESTART__EVENT__INITIALIZE====================================
)
call batch_lib\lib\setauto.bat
call batch_lib\lib\stop_all.bat
goto :EOF

:FUNC
set currentDir=%CD%
cd "%armapath%/batch_lib/gbl_func"
rem %1 = return var, %2 = function, %3 = args
set returnvarname=%1
set funcname=%2
set argString=%3
set argString=%argString:__= %
set argString=%argString:"=%
set argString=%argString:(=[%
set argString=%argString:)=]%
set args=%argString%
if "%argString%"=="__=" set args=
if "%argString%"=="" (
 set args=
)
set filename=%funcname%.cmd
set val1=
for /f %%I in ('%filename% "%args%"') do (
 set "val1=%%I"
)
set "%1=%val1%"
cd %currentDir%
goto :EOF
```

Thanks for your help!
Jayson

Comment: By the way, My start server batch is working perfect. When the server is running and i hit the restart batch the server does restart and create new logs.

Comment: Why you don't use scheduler? Add your task and set time repeat every 4 h?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just - waits 4 hours then reboots.

```
timeout /t 14400
shutdown /r /f /t 0
```